# Casting a JSON field to STRING in BigQuery's LoadJobConfig

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am pulling data from an API call and loading it into JSON before I load it into a bigquery table. I noticed there are some fields that contain both numbers and strings, however, on a daily load basis, it may not have both so the JSON schema will infer that field as INTEGER or STRING depending on what it contains that day.

The BigQuery table has this field as a STRING....Is there a way to cast this one field as a STRING in the JSON in BigQuery's LoadJobConfig before loading? Otherwise I get a "Provided Schema does not match table error on some days".

I'm super new to all this so I'm not sure if there is a better way.

This is my API call:

```
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
j = json.loads(response.text)
return j
```

Which then I load the results vi:

```
def insert_rows_append(table_name, rows):
    bq_client = get_big_query_client()
    print('Inserting {} rows into {}'.format(table_name, len(rows)))
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    # job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
    # bq_table = bq_client.table(ORDERS_TABLE)
    try:
        load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_json(
            rows,
            table_name,
            job_config=job_config
            #, row_ids=[None] * len(rows_to_insert)
        ) 

for row in rows:
        if 'ad_name' in row:
            if not isinstance(row['ad_name'], str): row['ad_name'] = str(row['ad_name'])
        if 'ad_group' in row:
            if not isinstance(row['ad_group'], str): row['ad_group'] = str(row['ad_group'])
```

I did some additional checks. Checking the "rows" that I am passing into `load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_json` using this:

```
def getList(dict):
        for key, value in dict.items():
            print(key, type(value))
    print(getList(rows[0]))
```

```
Inserting dev:test.table rows into 29090
ad <class 'str'>
ad_group <class 'str'>
ad_group_name <class 'str'>
ad_name <class 'str'>
browser <class 'str'>
campaign <class 'str'>
campaign_name <class 'str'>
click_through_rate <class 'NoneType'>
clicked_at_date <class 'str'>
clicked_at_hour <class 'int'>
clicks <class 'int'>
clicks_unique <class 'int'>
cost_amount <class 'float'>
cost_currency <class 'str'>
country <class 'str'>
goal_rate <class 'NoneType'>
goal_revenue_amount <class 'NoneType'>
goal_revenue_currency <class 'NoneType'>
goals <class 'list'>
impressions <class 'int'>
impressions_unique <class 'int'>
influencer <class 'str'>
network <class 'str'>
network_name <class 'str'>
sub1 <class 'str'>
sub2 <class 'str'>
sub3 <class 'str'>
sub4 <class 'str'>
sub5 <class 'str'>
team_id <class 'int'>
team_name <class 'str'>
user_id <class 'str'>
network_click_through_rate <class 'NoneType'>
network_clicks <class 'NoneType'>
network_cost_amount <class 'NoneType'>
network_cost_currency <class 'NoneType'>
network_impressions <class 'NoneType'>
None
error occurred
400 Provided Schema does not match Table dev:test.table. Field ad_name has changed type from STRING to INTEGER
```

So according to this, ad_name in the JSON is a string. So I do not know where INTEGER is coming from.

Edit: Looking into the values of the field. I'm seeing none types and string types values for the ad_name column. Does python categorize a field as INTEGER in a situation where you have nonetypes in a field?

Comment: This is a pretty solid question, but it needs the API call, JSON, and an example error. In other words consider adding an MRE, a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Updated the post. Super new to all this so let me know if there is anything else missing.

Comment: Since you are doing a `write_append`, Bigquery won't support updating data type of column on the fly. Can you not update the json data before loading?

Comment: @PeterJeong Much better!

Comment: @AnkurSaxena I took yoru advice but I am having some trouble atm. This is what I am doing to cast the values to a string:

```
for row in result['results']:
        if "ad_name" in row:
            row['ad_name'] == str(row['ad_name'])
```
This doesn't seem to be override the value though.

Comment: I see you are using `==` instead of `=`. Also, I would add a type check like this: `if not isinstance(row['ad_name'], str): row['ad_name'] = str(row['ad_name'])`

Comment: Still  running into an error. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by passing in a schema into `job_config.schema`

Seems like even with autodetect off, bigquery is somehow still doing something under the hood that tries to cast or convert fields.